# Typescript issue: array of number is missing properties I have never defined

Tags: typescript

I have a signup form, that includes a `location` field. `Location` is an array of two numbers (`latitude` and `longitude`), which is defined by a type `Geolocation`.

```js
type latitude = number;
type longitude = number;
export type GeoLocation = [latitude, longitude];

export interface SignupForm {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  location?: Geolocation;
}
```

When writing the signup form, the location field claims that:

> Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Geolocation': clearWatch, getCurrentPosition, watchPosition

I have no clearWatch, getCurrentPosition nor watchPosition in my type Geolocation. Why Typescript returns an error? Here is my form:

```js
{
    username: "myname",
    email: "mail@mail.com",
    password: "mypassword",
    location: [1.234, 5.678],
  }
```

Comment: JavaScript and TypeScript are case sensitive. You've used `Geolocation` (lower case `l`), not `GeoLocation` (upper case `L`), in your `location` declaration in `SignupForm`. So it's using the [`Geolocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) interface, not your interface.

Comment: I can't believe I haven't seen such a typo!!! Because of TS I'm used to see a red highlight each time I do a mistake, hence my stupid question. Thank you!

Comment: Side note: TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal. As a result, there's no point to `type longitude = number` in terms of type checking and it provides a bit of a false sense of security. There are a couple of ways you can do nominal-like things in TypeScript, such as branding. More in this article: https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/#approach-2-brands

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)

Comment: Just because I find it interesting, I thought I'd interject an opinion - whilst the addition of defining a type `type longitude = number;` doesn't serve a purpose in a structural type system, it does perhaps make it a little easier to understand. Not saying it's worth adding in this particular use case, and indeed it may actually be more confusing, but it _might_ serve a reasonable purpose to do that kind of type-alias definition, if it makes the code easier to understand

Comment: @OlivierRadini yes indeed, I could have just written [number, number], but I want to make sure another developper never invert latitude and longitude before sending the info in the db. It makes sense here.